# jqgrid: update parent row when row in subgrid is saved

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm using jqgrid 4.8.2. I have a parent grid with product quantity totals.  I've configured a subgrid (as a grid) that will display the quantity available for each warehouse that has the product.  For example:

```
ID    Category    Name            Quantity
1     Beverages   Steeleye Stout      1000

    WHSE ID   Whse Name   Quantity   Include?
    1         London            50        Yes
    2         Manchester        75         No
```

The Include column in the subgrid displays a checkbox when the row is being edited.

I need to update the Quantity cell in the parent row when any warehouse row in the subgrid is edited. The only edit available in the subgrid rows is to change the Include value to Yes or No.

Somehow, I need to capture the Include value in the warehouse row (in the subgrid) before it is edited, and after the row is saved, perform the appropriate update on the parent row's Quantity.  For example:

1. Warehouse row Include value changed from Yes to No: subtract
   quantity in warehouse row from quantity in parent row.
2. Warehouse row Include value changed from No to Yes: add quantity in warehouse row to quantity in parent row.

I'm not sure how to get the value of the Include cell in the subgrid row  before the save is committed. I'm also not sure from what event I would trigger the update to the parent row after the subgrid row save has taken place.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
var lastSelection;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    url: 'servlet/getData',
    datatype: "json",
    editurl: "servlet/updateProduct",
    page: 1, 
     colModel: [
        { label: 'ID', name: 'productId', width: 75, key: true },
        { label: 'Category', name: 'categoryName', width: 90 },
        { label: 'Name', name: 'productName', width: 100 },
        { label: 'Country', name: 'country', width: 80 },
        { label: 'Price', name: 'price', width: 80 },
        { label: 'Qty', name: 'quantity', width: 80 },
        { label: 'Included?', name: 'included', width: 80,
                editable: true, 
                edittype: "checkbox", 
                editOptions: {value:"Yes:No"} }
    ],
    viewrecords: true,
    onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
        var grid = $('#jqGrid');
        if (rowid && rowid !== lastSelection) {
            grid.jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSelection);
            lastSelection = rowid;
        }
        grid.jqGrid('editRow', lastSelection, {keys: true, 
            extraparam : {
                home: "livonia",
            }
        } 
        );

    },
    width: 780,
    height: 200,
    rowNum: 10,
    pager: "#jqGridPager",

    subGrid: true,
    subGridRowExpanded: function(subgrid_id, row_id) {
        var lastSelection;

        var grid = $('#jqGrid');
        var row = grid.getRowData(row_id);  
        var productId = row.productId;

           var subgrid_table_id = subgrid_id + "_table";
           var subgrid_pager_id = subgrid_id + "_pager";

           jQuery("#"+subgrid_id).html("<table id='"+subgrid_table_id+"' class='scroll'></table>" + 
                   "<div id='" + subgrid_pager_id + "'></div>");

           jQuery("#"+subgrid_table_id).jqGrid({
              url: 'servlet/getProductWarehouses?q=2&id=' + row_id + '&productId=' + productId,
              datatype: "json",
              editurl: "servlet/updateProductWarehouse",
                page: 1, 
                colModel: [
                    { label: 'Product ID', name: 'productId', width: 75, key: false, hidden: true },
                    { label: 'Whse ID', name: 'whseId', width: 60, key: true },
                    { label: 'Whse Name', name: 'whseName', width: 90 },
                    { label: 'Qty', name: 'quantity', width: 50 },
                    { label: 'Included?', name: 'included', width: 60,
                    editable: true, 
                    edittype: "checkbox", 
                    editOptions: {value:"Yes:No"} }
                ],
            viewrecords: true,

            onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
                var grid = $(this);
                if (rowid && rowid !== lastSelection) {
                    grid.jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSelection);
                    lastSelection = rowid;
                }
                grid.jqGrid('editRow', lastSelection, {keys: true, 
                    extraparam : {
                        productId: function(){
                            var row = grid.getRowData(lastSelection);
                            var temp = row['productId'];
                            return temp;
                        },
                    }
                } 
                );

            },

              height: '100%',
              width: 600,
              rowNum: 5,
            pager: "#" + subgrid_pager_id

           });
       }

});


});
```

I think I need to use the saveRow method, but I'm not sure when to call it, or how to get the cell values I need to do the parent row update.  How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Why the parent row should be modified on editing *child* subgrid? Is the parent row will be changed too? Do you save information about the subgrid in the data main grid? Which datatype you use? It's better to insert the code (JavaScript code) which clear what you do. Which kind of subgrids you use? If you use grid as subgrid (the recommended way) then you have rowid of the parent row and you can use `setCell` or `setRowData` to modify the parent row.

Comment: I revised this question completely to state exactly what I need to do.  If you can help me with this, you're help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question you need be able to save original sate of `included` column in subgrid *before* editing of a row of subgrid. After saving the changing of the row you want to adjust the value of `quantity` column of the parent row.

To implement the requirement you can use `aftersavefunc` callback of `editRow`. Before starting the `editRow` you can save the old value of `included`:

```
var origIncluded = grid.jqGrid('getCell', lastSelection, 'included');
```

then you can call `editRow` by specifying of additional `aftersavefunc` callback.

Before that I would recommend you to make `productId` column of subgrid editable and add the property `editrules: {edithidden: true}`:

```
{ label: 'Product ID', name: 'productId', width: 75,
    editable: true, hidden: true, editrules: { edithidden: true } }
```

As the result the value of `productId` will be included in the posted data. The call of `editRow` can be reduced to the following:

```
grid.jqGrid('editRow', lastSelection, {
    keys: true, 
    aftersavefunc: function (rowid, jqXHR, savedData) {
        if (savedData.included !== origIncluded) {
            var $mainGrid = $("#jqGrid"),
                subgridQuantity = parseFloat(grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'quantity')),
                mainGridQuantity = parseFloat($mainGrid.jqGrid('getCell', row_id, 'quantity'));
            mainGridQuantity += savedData.included === 'Yes' ?
                subgridQuantity : -subgridQuantity;
            $mainGrid.jqGrid('setCell', row_id, 'quantity', mainGridQuantity);
        }
    }
});
```

If it's not exactly what you need, then you can easy modify the above code to what you need.

Comment: Works perfectly!  Thanks!

Comment: After updating the row in the parent grid, if I go to the next page of the parent grid and then go back to the previous page of the parent grid, the change I previously made to the row in the parent grid is gone.  When I went back to the previous page, jqgrid retrieved that data over again.  Does this mean I need to persist that change to the row in the parent grid to the back-end database in order for it to be retained?  Or is there a way to tell jqgrid to cache previous rows retrieved?

Comment: @MichaelSobczak: I'm not sure that I understand correctly the problem. I suppose that the response from subgrid (from `url: 'servlet/getProductWarehouses?q=2&id=' + row_id + '&productId=' + productId,`) could be cached. Do you set any caching HTTP headers in the server response? I personally set `Cache-Control: private, max-age=0`. I recommend you to use Fiddler of Developer Tools of IE/Chrome/Firefox to see HTTP traffic in the scenario which you describe. You will see where you should search for the reason on the problem: on the client side or on the server side.

Comment: Its actually the parent grid where I don't want to loose the edits that were done by the subgrid.

Comment: With the **virtual load on demand example** on the web site, when I scroll down, jqgrid loads the next set of rows needed.  When I scroll back to rows previously displayed, jqgrid doesn't refetch those rows from the server. Is there a way to accomplish this when the pager is used?

Comment: @MichaelSobczak: I don't recommend you (or everybody else) to use virtual scrolling. Try that you have any problem with standard paging. By the way how many total rows you have in the main grid.

Comment: There could be over a hundred rows in the main (or parent) grid.

Comment: If you have only hundred rows in the main grid then I would recommend you to use `loadonce: true` scenario and local paging of data.

Comment: My problem is solved if I periodically commit the subgrid rows to the back-end. I'll be working through that logic later today. I appreciate your feedback on this!